# Need to include input at top in all controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, namespaces, laravel-5.5, laravel-request

Hi in my project there are many controllers and i want use input everywhere without including in controller at top like this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input; //or 
use Input; // if i create alias for the same in app.php
```

is there any way that without include i get input in whole system without including in all controller at top ?

Comment: probably too short for an answer but: you could create a generic controller for your application, and have all of your subsequent controllers inherit from it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's impossible. This is how PHP namespaces work, you should import them in each file.

About `Input` in fact it's Laravel 4 way, you don't use input now, you use `Illuminate\Http\Request` in Laravel 5. Additionally you can not import this class if you are fine with using Laravel `request()` helper, so in controller do get all the data from request/input you can now use:

```
$data = request()->all();
```